# how many ways can 1001 people win 500 identical items?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

the question is stating that $1001$ people are in a race and there are $500$ objects that are identical (say the same shirts).

We need to find the number of ways that the 500 shirts can be given out IF only the first $500$ people to finish the race get the shirts.

I know that since the shirts are identical, order shouldn't matter. What I propose is that since there are $n=1001$ people and $k=500$ shirts, it would be $\dbinom{n}{k}$. Pretty sure this isnt right because the number is huuge...

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number $\binom{1001}{500}=\frac{1001!}{500! \times 501!}$ seems correct to me too.

Another way of arguing this: there are $1001!$ possible race results (permutations of the people).  Permuting the first $500$ or the last $501$ does not affect who gets shirts.  So, given $500$ the people who win shirts, there are exactly $500! \times 501!$ ways they could have won them.  So we get $\frac{1001!}{500! \times 501!}$ possibilities.

Indeed, the number is quite huge:

```
540036984403956099970319976685830839863569182544899870847106323316830447373708016152716759298257230609836264852508119063686650618364731731471944339160115756285607085325380209759518216654326597268880117236089056092166898264954179976836558074278734888461642260398682633662848128817178049440446349376320
```

But that doesn't make it incorrect.  This is an example of [combinatorial explosion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorial_explosion).

Comment: thanks for the explanation, i guess i was just skeptical cuz it was an assignment question and we are only allowed a calculator. Doing 1001C500 gave an error. i guess they just expect us to write out 1001!/501!*500! then